# AWS EC2 Instance not showing access to Port 8000

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have setup an AWS EC2 Instance (g4dn.2xlarge). I wanted to setup a flask app on the same and run it using gunicorn and nginx on port 8000. Following all steps listed on multiple sites I did the following:

1. Updated Inbound Rules on my security group to allow HTTP:
   [Screenshot of Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA7DP.png)
2. Checked Outbound Rules:
   [Screenshot of Outbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSK11.png)
3. Connected to the VM using SSH and ran `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN.`

The output was:

```
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
 786/systemd-resolve 
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1058/sshd           
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      592/rpcbind         
 tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1058/sshd           
 tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      592/rpcbind         
 tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      966/java            
 tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      966/java            
 tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      966/java            
 tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN      966/java
```

Why is the system not showing port 8000 as available. I even ran grep 8000 and it gave no results. What should I do?

Comment: Did you setup your flask and it runs correctly?

Comment: Yes I ran flask on the vm. It runs perfectly well. Even locally on my desktop, the flask app works. But in the case for some reason 0.0.0.0/8000 is not available as a port even though its in my inbound rules.

Comment: So it runs correctly on the instance? You can `curl localhost:8000` on it?

Comment: When I run python app.py for my flask app - It launches on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ .

I ran curl on this address and that worked. But how do I get this to launch on 8000? So that I can access via web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the flask app port in app.py file

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

configure your web server (ex: nginx or apache) to proxy queries to flask port.

Comment: This worked! But I will just add one more point for others that may face similar problems:

While this was one of the things that I needed to do, another thing I had to do was to reset the APC and VPC of my AWS instance. I do not know how that worked but it fixed the error.