# Flask server running using private ip on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, server

I'm run my server on basic host and port

```
self.app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And server has running on 172.31.26.176:5000 but it my private AWS ip and page doesn't load.
If i select port (16324) server run with my port, but page also not loaded.
If i use my public AWS ip i take error.

> OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Its my first server. On the local machine he work normaly.

Comment: Did you open your AWS server's port to the world ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the route table of your subnet and ensure that route to internet (IGW) is added in it.
2. Check the security group of your EC2 and ensure inbound traffic is allowded for your flask port.

Then run the application and hit YOUR_AWS_EC2_PUBLIC_IP:5000 in browser.

> OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

This error was likely caused because the port/ip requested is already taken. Check whether flask app is already running on your requested address:port

Comment: Please tell me what should I write here [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/xvliZcv.png).
And this is defaulth security group [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/YrdeIY8.png).
And, what type of address should I provide for flask

Comment: In route table add 0.0.0.0/0 as destination and select your IGW in target. No modification required in security group as it is allowing all traffic to all ports. But this is not the best practise . And reg your last question, if you want to listen flask on all IP's of your EC2(private, public and loopback) put 0.0.0.0.If you need only on public IP then put your public IP. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67545262/aws-ec2-instance-not-showing-access-to-port-8000/67547441#67547441

Comment: thanks. First i do all of you say. But it don't help me. And i delet all rules and changes and started from the beginning and it work. Thanks

Comment: I'm running into this same issue... 

1. I have the route table destination as '0.0.0.0/0' and target as IGW.

2. Inbound traffic (TCP) allowed on the port I'm using

However, when running `python app.py` with the below code, it's still running on my EC2 instance's private IP address. 
```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is Public IP assigned to your EC2 ?

Comment: I am running into the same issue any solution of this?

Comment: added custom tcp / 5000 / allow from anywhere 0.0.0.0/0 in aws security group.